# Получить значение из функции JavaScript и записать его в C# переменную (в cshtml)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Здравствуйте! Вопрос в том как получить значение из функции JavaScript и записать его в C# переменную (в cshtml). Т.е. есть View (cshtml), JavaScript функция, показывающая диалоговое окно и C# переменная на этой View. Нужно выполнить JS функцию, а результат ее работы (если пользователь нажал ОК, то одно значение, если Cancel, то другое) записать в эту C# переменную. Возможно ли это вообще? Если да, то как? Спасибо за помощь!

*Update*

Есть View, на ней рисуется таблица. Перед отрисовкой проверяется количество записей в модели: если больше, например, 20 штук (проверка через @if) то выводится сообщение пользователю с вопросом "грузить все или только первых 20?", если пользователь жмет ОК, из модели берется только первых 20 записей (реализую через цикл @for, где ограничением выступает C# переменная). Т.е. нужно узнать какую кнопку нажал пользователь и соответственно подставить в цикл либо "20", либо число пришедших с моделью записей.

Comment: Нет. Когда javascript выполняется браузером, никаких C# переменных уже нет. Вам нужно что-то другое. Попробуйте объяснить еще раз.

Comment: Понятно, так я и думал. Вы уже пробовали, задать пользователю вопрос, или хотя бы показать сообщение, во время отработки View?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Это** не будет делать **то**. Чтобы начал выполняться javascript, View должен полностью отработать, и сгенеренный в результате html будет отправлен в браузер. И только там, во время загрузки страницы, скрипт будет выполнен. Вернуться в этот момент обратно в код View уже невозможно.

Вам нужно знать ответ пользователя заранее. Например, на странице, с которой пользователь попадает на страницу с таблицей, есть checkbox, значение которого уже будет известно на серверной стороне во время вызова View.

Или выводите сначала 20 записей и кнопку "Показать Все", и по нажатию кнопки перегружайте страницу, уже зная, что пользователь хочет видеть все записи.

Или используйте один из jQuery/Grid плагинов, поддерживающих постраничное отображение данных.

Comment: Спасибо! Отличные идеи!